# PHP case and accent insensitive search into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I have an array containing words, some of them with accents. I want to test if a given word is into that array but making it case and accent insensitive. For example:

```
$array = array("coche","camión","moto","carro");
```

i want a simple little function, something like `in_array`. If my string is `'Camion'` or `'camión'` it should return `true`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out: :-D

```
function check_array($array, $string){
   $trans = array("é" => "e", "&eacute;" => "e", "&aacute;" => "a", "á" => "a", "&iacute;" => "i","í"=>"i", "ó"=>"o", "&oacute;" => "o", "&uacute;" => "u", "ú"=>"u","&ouml;" => "u", "ü"=>"u");
   $realString = strtr($string,$trans);
   foreach($array as $val){
      $realVal = strtr($val,$trans);
      if(strcasecmp( $realVal, $realString ) == 0){
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

so to use it:

```
check_array($array, 'Camion');
```

using `strcasecmp` as per [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) suggestion

Comment: I don't believe that takes into consideration accents.

Comment: hmmmm true; ive got to add that. few mins

Comment: You can consider to use `strcasecmp`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Answer (score 2):

You should use iconv with TRANSLIT

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

But consider the iconv TRANSLIT is SO based. So the results aren't the same from machine to machine.

After you have normalized accents you can do a strtolower() or a search with REGEX /i

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to set up a translation table like so:

```
$translation = array(
    'from' => array(
        'à','á','â','ã','ä', 'ç', 'è','é','ê','ë', 'ì','í','î','ï', 'ñ',
        'ò','ó','ô','õ','ö', 'ù','ú','û','ü', 'ý','ÿ', 'À','Á','Â','Ã',
        'Ä','Ç', 'È','É','Ê','Ë', 'Ì','Í','Î','Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ',
        'Ö', 'Ù','Ú','Û','Ü', 'Ý')
    'to' => array(
        'a','a','a','a','a', 'c', 'e','e','e','e', 'i','i','i','i', 'n',
        'o','o','o','o','o', 'u','u','u','u', 'y','y', 'A','A','A','A','A',
        'C','E','E','E','E', 'I','I','I','I', 'N', 'O','O','O','O','O',
        'U','U','U','U', 'Y')
);
```

and then you can use [strtr](https://www.php.net/strtr) to do a translate in byte order:

```
$string = strtr("Camion",$translation['from'],$translation['to']);
```

following that it should all be in the English range `a-z A-Z`.

If your server supports `iconv` you can do something like so:

```
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $string);
```

Comment: strtr() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given