# Yii2: accent insensitive filter

Tags: postgresql, yii2, accent-insensitive

I want to search words using **accent insensitive**. For case insensitive I use **ilike**:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'name', $this->name]);
```

But for accent insensitive I don't know a Yii2 solution (else I can use this PHP [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330044/php-case-and-accent-insensitive-search-into-an-array)).

In the next example I search the word "camara" but it doesn't find the word "cámara" (means camera in Spanish):

[image: No results found]

Comment: umm.. well change the collation on runtime in your sql query, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql , you just need to tell MySQL to use a different collation.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam, but I prefer not to touch the PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using the **lower_unaccent PostgreSQL function** and the **ILIKE PostgreSQL operator**:

```
$query->andWhere(new Expression(
    'lower_unaccent(name) ILIKE \'%\' || lower_unaccent(\'' . $this->name . '\') || \'%\''
));
```

Comment: It looks like you have SQLi vulnerability in your query. You should use prepared statement and params instead of concatenation at PHP level.

Answer (score 0):

took me a while to make this work with @rob006 comment about sql injection:

```
private static function ExpressionLikeAccentInsensitive($col, $field){
        $bind = md5($col);
        return [
            'ilike',
            new Expression("lower(unaccent({$col}))"),
            new Expression("'%' || lower(unaccent(:q{$bind})) || '%'", [
                ":q{$bind}"=>$field
            ]),
        ];
    }
```

then you call it like this (example using Postgres ILKE):

```
$query->andFilterWhere(self::ExpressionLikeAccentInsensitive('"DB_COLUMN"', $this->DB_COLUMN));
```