# How can I access values of an array through a sanitized key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sanitization, associative

Let's say I have an associative array like this one:

**PHP**

```
   $array = array(
       'Corfù' => 'pita gyros',
       'San Gennaro'  => 'pizza',
       'Perù' => 'tortillias'
   );
```

How can I access values of this array through a sanitized key in php like this? **(possibly without loops)**

**PHP**

```
echo $array['corfu'];
// pita gyros

echo $array['san-gennaro'];
// pizza
```

instead of this

**PHP**

```
echo $array['Corfù'];
// pita gyros
```

This is because I'm taking the key from the url of a related page, that obviously is missing accents and white spaces

Comment: You cannot do this without a loop, or an implicit loop. With a loop it is relatively easy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330044/php-case-and-accent-insensitive-search-into-an-array

Comment: _Why_ are your array keys like this to begin with? Are you intending to use them for output to the end user in the frontend at some point? If not, it would probably make much more sense, that you used keys that actually match the values you get passed from the outside in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe yes I need to pass the keys from the backend to the frontend, this is for populate the title of the page and some tables, so I need to render the correct word. Maybe I can use a key like corfu and add an additional value inside like "render" => "Corfù", but I think that this is a little annoying.

Comment: _“but I think that this is a little annoying”_ - No, that is rather how you _should_ be doing this. Separate actual _logic_, from how you need stuff to _display_. Otherwise, you’ll get into even bigger trouble, when what the front-end needs to show changes at some point, or when you might want to add a second language.

Answer (score 0):

```
function seola($s)
{
    $tr = array('ş', 'Ş', 'ı', 'İ', 'ğ', 'Ğ', 'ü', 'Ü', 'ö', 'Ö', 'Ç', 'ç','ù');
    $eng = array('s', 's', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'g', 'u', 'u', 'o', 'o', 'c', 'c', 'y','u');
    $s = str_replace($tr, $eng, $s);
    $s = strtolower($s);
    $s = preg_replace('/&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;.+?;/', '', $s);
    $s = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 \/_-]/', '', $s);
    $s = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $s);
    $s = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $s);
    $s = trim($s, '-');
    $s = substr($s, 0, 60);
    return $s;
}

  $array = array(
            'Corfù' => 'pita gyros',
            'San Gennaro' => 'pizza',
            'Perù' => 'tortillias'
        );

       foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
           $array[seola($key)] = $array[$key];
           unset($array[$key]);
       }
print_r($array);
/*
Array
(
    [corfu] => pita gyros
    [san-gennaro] => pizza
    [peru] => tortillias
)
*/
```

its look like more useful
//

Comment: Hi Berkan Kaya, Can you explain your code and how it solves the question?

Comment: this solution works, but i thought there was some sort of php inbuild function to solve the issue without loops

Comment: Unfortunately :( if have be another method i don't know, keep going to research. By the way why dont you use to the loop @silvered.dragon

Comment: there is nothing to explain. I just edit to key using seola function for more useful. @bsheps

Comment: @BerkanKaya yes you are right.. it's just because this becomes really complex if I have deep nested arrays(and this is my final case), I have to loop through each level

Comment: @silvered.dragon Yes little bit :( i'm sorry for you. But its look like only this solution solve this issue for now

Comment: @silvered.dragon But i will do added to solution if you want to the nested array too